# How to return records in a view based off of a selected Item's data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, controller

I am creating an asp.net MVC application for a small animal breeder. I have the database set up with one table called AvailableAnimals with has a one to many relationship with a MaleBreeder table and a FemaleBreeder table. I am wanting to create a 'siblings' page from using a selected available animal's ID and being able to view all the full and half siblings to this animal. This is what I have so far, but the Siblings view does not return anything.

The answer is I'm sure a simple one that I just cant think of right now.

CONTROLLER:

```
    public ActionResult Siblings(int? id)
    {

        AvailableAnimals availableAnimals = db.AvailableAnimals.Find(id);
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        else if (id != null)
        {

            var siblings = db.AvailableAnimals.Where(x => x.ACSireID == id.Value || x.ACDamID == id.Value);
            return View(siblings);
        }

        if (availableAnimals == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(availableAnimals);
    }
```

My view currently is only set up to display the siblings from a simple foreach loop.

Comment: Did you debug the code? What data you are getting in `availableAnimals` and `siblings` variables?

Comment: availableAnimals is the table I am pulling in records from. that table has data for ACSIREID and ACDAMID. I have a seperate table for the sires and a separate table for the dams. So they have a one to many relationship to the available animals. Siblings I just have as a variable right now.

Comment: You code looks ok. The probable reason you are not getting data in the view is because you are not getting any data in `siblings` variable. You need to debug your code and check if you are getting any data in `siblings` variable or not. You also need to check if you have proper data in your database. You only can debug your code. We can hint you about where to look for the problem. We can's solve the problem because we don't know what is the problem.

Comment: So the only thing my variable 'siblings' is returning is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SolutionName.AvailableAnimals]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.....

It was only bringing in that animal's ID, and comparing the dam and sire ID's to the that. here is what ended up working......

public ActionResult Siblings(int? id)
    {

```
    AvailableAnimals availableAnimals = db.AvailableAnimals.Find(id);
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    else if (id != null)
    {

        var siblings = db.AvailableAnimals.Where(x => x.ACSireID == availableAnimals.ACSireID || x.ACDamID == availableAnimals.ACDamID).Include(x => x.FemaleBreederAnimals).Include(x => x.MaleBreederAnimals);
        return View(siblings);
    }

    if (availableAnimals == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(availableAnimals);
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Siblings(int? id)
{

    AvailableAnimals availableAnimals = db.AvailableAnimals.Find(id);
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    else if (id != null)
    {

        List<AvailableAnimals> siblings = db.AvailableAnimals.Where(x => x.ACSireID == id || x.ACDamID == id).ToList();
        return View(siblings);
    }

    if (availableAnimals == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(availableAnimals);
}
```

Checkout Your AvailableAnimals table must be count > 0 then you able to parse data using foreach loop and your view look like this

```
@model List<SolutionName.ModelName.AvailableAnimals>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I appreciate it, I'll give it a try! :)

Comment: Nothing changed after implementing this. I did find, however, that the only thing I am getting back from the siblings variable is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SolutionName.AvailableAnimals].